# Incorrect output when using sizeof()

Tags: c++

I am defining my structure like:

```
struct Shape {
unsigned int l;  // value for length 
unsigned int h;  // value or height
unsigned int b;  // value for breadth
};
```

In my program I am allocating an instance of Shape dynamically:

```
Shape *image = new Shape[i];
```

and I am trying to print out the size of it :

```
cout<< "The size of image is " << sizeof(image)<< ends;
```

Irrespective of what the value of i is I am getting the same output:(ex: 0, 1, 2,10)

```
The size of the image is 8
```

Why is this?

Note: But when I apply the sizeof operator to the Shape structure, then I get the right answer:

```
sizeof(Shape) -> returns 12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> The size of the image is 8
> ```
>
> Why is this?

The output is correct, `sizeof(image)` gives you the size of the pointer variable `Shape*` itself, not the size of the allocated array.

Comment: I am trying to get the size of array, how can i get it?

Comment: @Mathew You simply can't with a pointer, you need to keep track of it yourself. That information is not present. Use a `std::vector<Shape>` instead, an don't try to manage `new` `delete` yourself.

Answer (score 4):

`image` is of type `Shape*`, not of type `Shape`, so `sizeof(image)` gives the size of `Shape*`.

Try `sizeof(*image)` instead.

Comment: sizeof(*image) now gives me 12 irrespective of the value of i. My declaration is   Shape *image = new Shape[10] ;

Comment: @Mathew `sizeof(*image)` is the same as `sizeof(Shape)`, therefore you will get 12 because `Shape` has 3 `int` members which are 4 bytes each on your system. Are you trying to get the size of the array?

Comment: @bku_drytt yes i am trying to get the size of array so that i can dynamically increase the size when needed